# OWL restrictions for must

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, description-logic

I'm fairly new to OWL and still learning the restrictions. I am trying to model these statements:

1. A person (P) can be male (M) or female (F), but not both
2. A person must be male or female
3. A male has no dresses
4. A female has at least one dress (D)

So far, I have modeled it like:

```
P -> canBe -> M  
P -> canBe -> F  
M <- disjoint -> F  
F -> has (>= 1) -> D
```

I'm confused as to how to add the restriction that a person **must** be male or female and how to show that a male has **no** dresses. I'm also unsure of my modeling in general and would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there can be different ways of achieving the same goal.  That means that the following answers aren't necessarily the *only* possibility, but they're the first ones that come to my mind.

> 1. A person (P) can be male (M) or female (F), but not both.
>   2. A person must be male or female.

For these two statements, there's an important modeling decision to make.  Are *Male* and *Female* each *subclasses*  of a *Person* class, or are you using some property, e.g., *hasSex* that relates  person to a sex?  If you're using the subclass approach, then you can do this by declaring that

> *Person* is the disjoint union of *Male* and *Female*.

This means that every instance of *Person* is an instance of *Male* or an instance of *Female*, and that the classes *Male* and *Female* are disjoint, so nothing is an instance of both.  (Of course, if you can talk about non-person things that male and female, then you wouldn't want to use this approach exactly.)

If you're using a property like *hasSex*, then it's either an object property or a data property.  In the first case, you'd need a class *Sex* with two individuals *male* and *female*, and you'd declare that they are different from each other, and you could make *hasSex* a functional property, and declare its range to be the class *Sex*.  Some of this depends on how general your classes and properties are, of course.  If you don't declare a range for the property, then you'd still want to use some sort of restriction class as a superclass of *Person*.  E.g.,

> Person ⊑ =1 hasSex.{male,female}
>   Person ⊑ ∀hasSex.{male,female}

These axioms say that each person has exactly one value from {male, female} as a value for the *hasSex*property, and that every value a person has for *hasSex* must be from {male, female}.

> 3. A male has no dresses
>   4. A female has at least one dress (D)

If you're using a general *has* property that can apply to more than just dresses (as opposed to, for instance, a *hasDress* property that applies only to dresses), and you have a class for *Dress*, these are simply:

> Male ⊑ =0 has.Dress
>   Female ⊑ ≥1 has.Dress

Comment: Thanks! That was a great in-depth answer. If I simply do not draw any relation between `Male` and `Dress` is that enough to conclude that a `male has no dresses` or would I still need to draw the relation `M -> hasDress = 0 -> D`?

Comment: OWL makes the [open world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_world_assumption);  just because you haven't said something doesn't mean that it couldn't be true.  The class "has max 0 Dress" is the class of individuals that can be _proven_ to have zero dresses.  Just because you don't know that someone has a dress doesn't mean that they don't, and OWL respects that.  If Males have no dresses, you need an axiom saying that.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again for your detailed explanations!